# Twitter Bootstrap - How do I get my carousel to, well, "carousel"?

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Generally I am always way over my head with programming, but I'm doing my best. Please be nice!

I watched a nice tutorial on YouTube in order to build myself a carousel in my Django project.

But instead of showing one image at a time it is just stacking all three on top of each other. I'm sure there's something simple that I've missed.

Please help me to fix this with a minimal of code change.

Here is my current HTML code. I don't believe the CSS is important at this point:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="main-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <!-- indicators (dot nav): -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>  
                <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- wrapper for slides: -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src='{% static "images/carousel1.jpg" %}' alt="string players"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Text here</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src='{% static "images/carousel2.jpg" %}' alt="string players"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>More text here</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src='{% static "images/carousel3.jpg" %}' alt="string players"/>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>Even more text here</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- next/prev navigation controls: -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in case the version of Bootstrap is where the problem lies, here is my meta, which has the version of Bootstrap I am using on the project:

```
<head>
<title>HCMN : {{ page_name }}</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Load CSNs (same for all templates): -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load CSS files (from each template): -->
{% block load_css %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you SO MUCH for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Nevermind. I needed "carousel-item" as a class instead of "carousel"! I love it when I can answer my own questions...